# why the video has no voice after downloaded

Tags: python

for the below code after video downloaded I found there is no voice and silence video and after minutes 6 giving me a black screen

```
import pytube
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UM6YDJ2aalU&t=185s'

video = pytube.YouTube(url)

stream = video.streams.get_by_itag(299)
print('downloading....')
stream.download(filename="youtube download")
print('done ')
```

Comment: this is due to the itag--> 299. which give u only video

Comment: that black screen thing didn;t happen to me. You must be having some network issue or ur net speed is fluctuating.

Comment: check out the documentation of the [Pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `299` itag number which is having `progressive=False`. Hence not allowing to have audio file. If it's True then it will allow you to have both the audio as well as video file.

progressive (bool) – Excludes adaptive streams (one file contains both audio and video tracks).

```
 <Stream: itag="299" mime_type="video/mp4" res="1080p" fps="60fps" vcodec="avc1.64002a" progressive="False" type="video">,
```